# Unlink a CSS stylesheet from specific page/div/tag

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website management utility for a friend of mine. In the index page, I have a link to a CSS stylesheet that came with a template I've bought. I use CKEditor to edit files, but the CSS stylsheet applies many bad styles to the editor.

I am not quite familiar with CSS (that's why I bought the template...) and I want to unlink the stylesheet only from the div/tag. I don't want to unlink it from the whole page, because it uses the stylesheet.

```
<div style="UNLINKED">   [CKEDITOR CODE GOES HERE]    </div>
```

I don't know if it is possible, but I need to do something with it.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting your CKEditor code on it's own HTML file (without a stylesheet) and inserting it into your page with an `iframe` instead of a `div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so the solution may be different for every dev. if it's ckeditor, try deleting the table selectors. for me the problem was with the `<td>` selector. thanks for the answers...

Answer (score 1):

You must override the styles, there is no way to "unlink" a specific element from the page styles.
Therefore, for example, if your stylesheet defines bold text for all paragraphs like this:

```
p { font-weight: bold; }
```

you have to override that to bring the paragraph back to normal text:

```
div.unlinked p { font-weight: normal; }
```

Comment: I know I can override the styles, but It's a problem when I don't know what are the styles. When I hover on the editor, it changes it's color. I didn't find any match for it in the stylesheet. maybe it's something connected to js/jquery.

Comment: You are using a source code analyzer like Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, right?

Comment: yeah, I use G Chrome dev tool. CKEditor changes it to JScript. I have no idea how to view the styles. that's the point

Comment: I see two things here: 
1) You know what your template css styles are, so you can override those to remove the colors, fonts, etc, for the div you want to have "clean". 
2) CKEditor has its own styles and they can be customized, see http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles

Comment: override all the styles is a really big work (2371 rows) and it's not something with ckeditor, when I unlink the whole website from the stylesheet it works, and it's flashing, not just problem with colors.

Comment: Check for the rendered HTML elements to see which styles to override, not the 2371 rows. Sorry, there is no way around, good luck =)

Comment: btw, check for the :hover style to see how an element changes color on mouse over

Answer (score 1):

Assign a class to the div and create style for it- the styles defined in the class will override global styles.

```
div.nostyle {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0 none;
}

<div class="nostyle">CKEDITOR CODE</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work :( When I hover on the editor it changes it color. I need different CSS styles maybe?

Comment: @ninja, If you want to apply an entire CSS reset to one class, you're going to need a lot more code than that.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot unlink the stylesheet once if was linked on the beginning.
Only some circumstances can help:

1. put the all the `<div ... </div>` period into an iframe.
2. or override all the style elements of the div

Comment: An Iframe will break all the code i've written, and I don't know how to override the elements, because i didn't find any elements connected to my problem (color change on hover) and because Ckeditor changes everythind to JS in the browser. Maybe problem of JS/Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would advise embedding the code into an iframe element. Otherwise, there is no way to avoid the cascade without overwriting every rule affecting the content with more specific rules.

Answer (score 0):

Easy! All you have to do is delete the  code at the top of the HTML! Once you do, the page automatically unlinks from the stylesheet. No need to override what was provided. :)

Comment: I think he is interested in unlinking the stylesheet *only* from the specific div. Removing the link to the stylesheet will eliminate *all* styles.